# Azure B2C - Do we need to create one B2C tenants for each separate customer or a single B2C tenant for all customers? what is the best practice?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I need to implement Azure B2C muli-tenant application and different customers will also be on-boarded to this application. We need to use Azure B2C to allow users register with their social accounts.

Do we need to have one B2C tenant corresponding to one customer or we can use a single B2C tenant for all customers ? What is the best practice around these two options ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether the customers are tightly or loosely related to one another.

For example,

- Customers comprise of Business A, Business B and Business C.
- Each customer will have many users.
- Customers are completely separate and billing needs to be very distinct

In the above scenario, I would set up different tenants for each 'customer'.

I'd say it is driven by your billing model; [read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/billing#upgrade-to-monthly-active-users-billing-model), and how manageable is it to set up separate tenants per 'customer'.